# Longitudinal study - conversion long to wide - implications

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, dataset

I'm doing a longitudinal study and trying to find out patterns before a defined event happens. For instance, we have data:

```
ID Date Amount Feature Event_ind
1  2010 5      M       0
1  2011 4      M       0
1  2012 3      M       1
```

The objective is to 'predict' the time when there would be an event happening, given historical data.
Currently, we are exploring whether we can convert this long table to a wide table. The table would look like:

```
ID Date1 Amount1 Date2 Amount2 Feature
1  2010  5       2011  4       M
```

My question is, what are the **implications of this conversion?** (or any good blog/academic paper explaining this)

One of the implications that I can think of is, in a wide table each repeated measurements have its own distribution; and this conversion doesn't make sense if it's measured in different time or at different frequency.